# C# Regex -- Matching multiple times between 2 same words and their children lines

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have text like this:

```
 INIT -- FOO
   UP: 1
     UpLine #1
   DOWN: 2
     DownLine #1
     DownLine #2

  INIT -- BAR
   UP: 0
   DOWN: 2
     DownLine #1
     DownLine #2
```

I want to basically capture information like for INIT -- BAR, I have 1 up, 2 down, and their contents ... and then same for INIT -- FOO ...

I just can't figure out how to do this ... INIT is a constant and FOO and BAR are variables that change.

Comment: do you have to use regex? I'm not sure I can think of a worse tool for this job!

Comment: I'm with a grammar generator, etc. like antlr or tinyPG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that uses named capture groups to keep track of all the different pieces:

```
INIT\s*--\s*(?<label>\w+)\n
\s+UP:\s*(?<up>\d+)\n
(?<uplines>(?:\s+(?!\s*DOWN).*\n)*)
\s+DOWN:\s*(?<down>\d+)\n
(?<downlines>(?:\s+(?!\s*INIT).*\n)*)
```

I know it's a little messy, but it works!

`INIT\s*--\s*(?<label>\w+)\n` matches the INIT line and captures the "label" group

`\s+UP:\s*(?<up>\d+)\n` matches the UP line and the "up" number in a group

`(?<uplines>(?:\s+(?!\s*DOWN).*\n)*)` gets any "uplines" before the DOWN line

`\s+DOWN:\s*(?<down>\d+)\n` matches the DOWN line and the "down" number in a group

`(?<downlines>(?:\s+(?!\s*INIT).*\n)*)` gets any "downlines" before the next INIT

Try it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tW7cM9/1).

**Notes**:

- I used the "extended" flag on regex101 to make it easier to read. C# supports that option as "IgnorePatternWhitespace", but to use it in C#, wrap all the lines together.
- Your environment may have different line-breaks. Most likely `\r\n` instead of `n`.

Comment: @RBJ: You collapsed it all into one line? Did you see the regex101 link to verify that it (theoretically) does what you want?

Comment: Ok, as the example is pasted does work .. if i switch to \r\n .. but I have a couple of weird characters like \ and : in my label and lines

Comment: @RBJ: If your labels have characters other than letters, change the `\w+` to `.+` and it should work.

Comment: [A-Za-z0-9.: \\]* gets me what i want instead of \w+